# Layout quebrado - participação

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Notei que no perfil, aba participação o texto `melhores %d deste trimestre` está sobreposto a outros elementos.

Isso aconteceu no firefox 40.0.3, fiz testes com o Chrome 45.0.2454.85 e  MS Egde 20.10240 o problema não foi encontrado neles. Resolução da tela 1366 x 768

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: It seems to be ok right now, isn't it?

Comment: @Paweł Yeah, I think the new translation fixed it. Thanks for checking it, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tradução foi mudada para uma um pouco menor, e resolveu o problema